# how to retrieve the html source code of popup window with userscript and tempermonkey

Tags: popupwindow, tampermonkey, userscripts

There's a *userscript* that I want to run on the content of a *popup window*.
The problem is that popup window doesn't trigger the script so i dont know how to get the text/html of the popup window (the website is written with angularjs)

Is there a way with userscript to get the content of the popup window?

**EDIT**
the popup window doesnt have an address bar.. does it matter?

Comment: I *think* all you'd have to do is make your userscript directives match the URL of the popup window, is that not working for you?

Comment: I got @match *, that what u mean? btw the popup window doesnt havre an adress bar if it matterS?

Comment: Windows *do* need an address - even if you can't see it, it's still there, re-enable it or examine the page and then you can debug using the page normally. Once that's working, it should work in the popup too